# After reading in bytes from file, most are right except 1 is wrong and negative

Tags: java, hex, byte

In Java, I just read a file into a ByteBuffer. When I started checking to make sure that the ByteBuffer contained the right bytes, I noticed that it had mostly the correct start and end bytes, except for the 3rd byte, it has -117 instead of what emacs says should be 139 (8b in hexl-mode). What gives? Does this have something to do with Big/Little Endian..?

Just to be clear, according to emacs the first four bytes should be:

1f:8b:08:00 which is equal to 31 139 8 0

and my java gets:

31 -117 8 0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java `byte` is signed, and therefore its range is -128..127 rather than 0..255. Taking that into account, your bytes are correct. If the unsigned value of the byte is `X`, signed one is `(X - 256)` - thus, for `139`, the signed value is `139 - 256 = -117`.

Comment: does that mean 0-127 are the same for both (a java 0 == the other 0) but everything after 128 in the other corresponds to a negative java byte?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've edited the question to detail the transformation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Java's integral types (including `byte`) are *signed*: they range from -128 to 127, rather than 0 to 255 like you might expect. Any number with a high bit of 1 (1### ####) will be negative.

[Lots of people have written about this.](http://www.darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a tangent, but if you are trying to work with signed bytes, the following might prove useful.

Since most operations will promote a Java `byte` to `int`—preserving the sign and magnitude—it is very common to mask off the high-order bits, like this:

```
/* Convert two bytes from an array to a 16-bit, unsigned value. */
int val = (b[idx] & 0xFF) << 8 | (b[idx + 1] & 0xFF);
```

Before applying the `&` operator (and most other operators), a `byte` is widened to an `int` (or even a `long`, depending on the context). So a signed byte value of `0xFF` is converted to a signed integer value of `0xFFFFFF`.

But normally when doing bit-wise operations, the intent to to treat each byte as an unsigned value, so the `byte` `0xFF` (-1) should just be the `int` `0xFF` (255). The masking with `0xFF` accomplishes this.